# MongoDB - find document whose array length is less than or equal to 5

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Can't we pass an object to `$size` operator in mongoose? Is there any ways to query on array for length so we can fetch document which contains an array of a particular length.

**Hers is Sample Document**

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8c9becd1257f66c4b8cd63"),
    "index" : 0,
    "name" : "Aurelia Gonzales",
    "isActive" : false,
    "registered" : ISODate("2015-02-11T09:52:39.000+05:30"),
    "age" : 20,
    "gender" : "female",
    "eyeColor" : "green",
    "favoriteFruit" : "banana",
    "company" : {
        "title" : "YURTURE",
        "email" : "aureliagonzales@yurture.com",
        "phone" : "+1 (940) 501-3963",
        "location" : {
            "country" : "USA",
            "address" : "694 Hewes Street"
        }
    },
    "tags" : [
        "enim",
        "id",
        "velit",
        "ad",
        "consequat"
    ]
}
```

**Here is query**

```
db.admin.aggregate([
    {
        $match : {tags : {$size : {$lte : 5}}}
    }
])
```

**Here is Output**

```
{
    "message" : "$size needs a number",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue",
    "name" : "MongoError"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `$size` like that & needed to use aggregation `$size` operator to do this.

**Query :**

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: { /** Allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language  */
    $lte: [
      {
        $size: "$tags"
      },
      5
    ]
  }
})
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mBYIc3sPm1E)

Answer (score 0):

Although if the size of the array is important enough, it could be stored in the documents and indexed to fetch much faster results.

Following a similar logic a solution could be, two stage aggregation using [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) and `$size`, `$lte`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      sizeOfTags: {
        $size: "$tags"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      sizeOfTags: {
        $lte: 5
      }
    }
  }
])
```